# Efficiently find the first of many keywords in a large NSString

Tags: objective-c, regex, string, performance, cocoa

I need to find all of the keywords in a large `NSString` (for a parsing source code), and my current implementation is too slow, but I'm unsure how to improve it.

I'm using `NSRegularExpression`, based on the assumption it is more optimised than anything I could write, but the performance is slower than I'd expect. Does anyone know of a faster way to implement this?

The target string will contain utf-8 characters, but the keywords themselves will always be plain alphanumeric ascii. I imagine this could be used to optimise things quite a bit?

```
@implementation MyClass

// i'm storing the regular expression in a static variable, since it never changes and I need to re-use it often
static NSRegularExpression *keywordsExpression;

+ (void)initialize
{
  [super initialize];

  NSArray *keywords = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"accumsan", @"adipiscing", @"aliquam", @"aliquet", @"amet", @"ante", @"arcu", @"at", @"commodo", @"congue", @"consectetur", @"consequat", @"convallis", @"cras", @"curabitur", @"cursus", @"dapibus", @"diam", @"dolor", @"dui", @"elit", @"enim", @"erat", @"eros", @"est", @"et", @"eu", @"felis", @"fermentum", @"gravida", @"iaculis", @"id", @"imperdiet", @"integer", @"ipsum", @"lacinia", @"lectus", @"leo", nil];

  NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b(%@)\\b", [keywords componentsJoinedByString:@"|"]; // \b(accumsan|adipiscing|aliquam|…)\b
  keywordsExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern] options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
}

// this method will be called in quick succession, I need it to be a able to run tens
// of thousands of times per second. The target string is big (50KB or so), but the
// search range is short, rarely more than 30 characters
- (NSRange)findNextKeyword:(NSString *)string inRange:(NSRange)range
{
  return [keywordsExpression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options:0 range:range];
}

@end
```

***EDIT*** As per @CodeBrickie's answer, I've updated my code to perform the regex search once on the whole string, and save the matches to a cached `NSIndexSet`, then each time the method is called it searches the `NSIndexSet` for keyword ranges instead of searching the string. The result is about an order of magnitude faster:

```
@implementation MyClass

static NSRegularExpression *keywordsExpression;
static NSIndexSet *keywordIndexes = nil;

+ (void)initialize
{
  [super initialize];

  NSArray *keywords = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"accumsan", @"adipiscing", @"aliquam", @"aliquet", @"amet", @"ante", @"arcu", @"at", @"commodo", @"congue", @"consectetur", @"consequat", @"convallis", @"cras", @"curabitur", @"cursus", @"dapibus", @"diam", @"dolor", @"dui", @"elit", @"enim", @"erat", @"eros", @"est", @"et", @"eu", @"felis", @"fermentum", @"gravida", @"iaculis", @"id", @"imperdiet", @"integer", @"ipsum", @"lacinia", @"lectus", @"leo", nil];

  NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b(%@)\\b", [keywords componentsJoinedByString:@"|"]; // \b(accumsan|adipiscing|aliquam|…)\b
  keywordsExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern] options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
}

- (void)prepareToFindKeywordsInString:(NSString *)string
{
  NSMutableIndexSet *keywordIndexesMutable = [[NSIndexSet indexSet] mutableCopy];
  [keywordsExpression enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    [keywordIndexesMutable addIndexesInRange:match.range];
  }];

  keywordIndexes = [keywordIndexesMutable copy];
}

- (NSRange)findNextKeyword:(NSString *)string inRange:(NSRange)range
{
  NSUInteger foundKeywordMax = (foundCharacterSetRange.location == NSNotFound) ? string.length : foundCharacterSetRange.location;
  NSRange foundKeywordRange = NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0);
  for (NSUInteger index = startingAt; index < foundKeywordMax; index++) {
    if ([keywordIndexes containsIndex:index]) {
      if (foundKeywordRange.location == NSNotFound) {
        foundKeywordRange.location = index;
        foundKeywordRange.length = 1;
      } else {
        foundKeywordRange.length++;
      }
    } else {
      if (foundKeywordRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return foundKeywordRange;
}

@end
```

This seems to work well, and has the performance up into the range of where I want it. I'd like to wait a bit longer to see if there are more suggestions before accepting this one though.

Comment: Just a side note - Your `findNextKeyword:inRange:` method shouldn't be accepting a *pointer* to an `NSRange`.

Comment: thanks @JacobRelkin, I've just edited that. This isn't my actual code, it's just the part that instruments tells me is too slow (95% of my CPU time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need the keywords along with their ranges, I would use `enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:` and implement a block that adds the keyword as a key and the range as a value to a `NSMutableDictionary`.

So you have only one call for the whole string and all the keywords with their ranges in the dictionary after that call.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but I still need to access the results of that search one at a time inside the `-findNextKeyword:inRange:` method I've posted here. Can you think of a good way to index the search results by range, so they can be looked up by this method? The method is being used to parse source code in real time for a text editor (which I'll probably open source some time in the coming weeks).

Comment: I'm going to try creating an NSIndexSet of every character in the string that matches any of the keywords.

Comment: I've updated by question to include an implementation of your answer. it works well (order of magnitude faster).

Comment: Updated my question again, with an even better implementation. `[string hash]` was very slow (it looks like `NSString` doesn't cache the result), so now I've moved the `NSIndexSet` build code out into a separate method which is now called once before I start parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assembling a regex to match all the keywords, I suggest you use a very basic regex to match any word, then look up the matched word in a Dictionary containing your keywords; if the word isn't there, ignore it move on.

You can tailor the regex to what you know about the keywords for maximum efficiency.  For example, if you know you're only looking for words of three to twelve lowercase ASCII letters, you could use `@"\\b[a-z]{3,12}+\\b"`.  Compared to your monster regex with its dozens of alternatives.

I've used this technique with great success in a syntax highlighter project of my own. That was in Java, but a quick look at the `NSRegularExpression` docs turns up a remarkably similar feature set.

Comment: I don't think this will be a good fit in my case, since the vast majority of words will not be keywords. But I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Does that include words that are inside string literals, comments, etc.?  This regex should never even see those.

Comment: I agree my regex is probably a tiny bit slower, but the next step you're suggesting, to check if every word in the file is in an `NSDictionary`, will surely be slow? I'll try it out.

Comment: Sorry, but your suggestion is 25% slower than using a complicated regex pattern that only matches the words I'm looking for. No doubt your pattern is faster, but there's a big performance hit checking if each result needs to be kept or thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you switch the search to some NSLiteral search instead of case insensitive?

Of course you need case insensitive, but if it's way faster it will give you ideas.

Max speed would be a lot more work and involve a lower cased c string and strstr(), I would bet.

Comment: I need it to be case insensitive. I realise C code might be faster, but I'm not comfortable enough with C to write it myself.